# Override user_login_submit in Drupal 6 to redirect an authenticated user

Tags: drupal, authentication, customizing

I would like to redirect a user that logged in over the user login block. What I have is a module that contains the following code:

Appendix, 3.9.2011, 15:30h: Changed code according to the advice of kiamlaluno.

Appendix, 3.9.2011, 17:08h: Small Fix: Changed node/admin to admin.

Appendix, 3.9.2011, 17:24h: removed `[]` 
-> code is working like this now, but do not forget to change the module priority in DB.

```
function _MYMODULE_user_login_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  global $user;
  if ($user->uid == 1) {
    $form_state['redirect'] = 'admin';
  } elseif ($user->uid) {
    $form_state['redirect'] = 'node/add/image';
    return;
  }
}

/**
 * Modifies the outfit and behaviour of the user login block.
 */
function MYMODULE_form_user_login_block_alter(&$form, $form_state) {
    unset($form['#action']);
    // removes the forgot password and register links
    $form['links'] = array();
    // Redirects the user to the image upload page after login
    // This cannot be done by a rule, the rule based redirect is only
    // working for the login page not the user login block.
    $form['#submit'] = array('_MYMODULE_user_login_submit');
}
```

It doesn't redirect users; it seems like `_MYMODULE_user_login_submit()` is simply ignored.

What I know already:

- I cannot use Rules/Triggers, because I do not login over the login page but the user login block
- It is always said: "use logintoboggan" on posts, but there I only have redirection options for "on registration" and "on confirmation", but I need "on authentication" or "after login".
- Anyway, I do not want to use more modules, I prefer a few lines of PHP.

Comment: Just a side note - the admin has uid 1 (your code checks for 0, which would be the anonymous user).

Comment: @HenrikOpel: good point. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because [user_block_login()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_login_block/6) sets the "#action" property for the form; in that case, redirecting the form after submission doesn't work.

```
  $form = array(
    '#action' => url($_GET['q'], array('query' => drupal_get_destination())), 
    '#id' => 'user-login-form', 
    '#validate' => user_login_default_validators(), 
    '#submit' => array('user_login_submit'),
  );
```

To make it work, you should first unset `$form[#action]`, and then executing the code you already execute in your `hook_form_alter()` implementation.

As side notes, I will add:

- If you want to be sure your code effectively redirect the user where you want, be sure your module is executed for last; if any other module that implements `hook_form_alter()` adds a form submission handler to redirect the user to a different page, and that module is executed after yours, then your module would not have any effect. To make sure your module is executed after the others, you should use code similar to the following during the installation of the module, or in an update hook. (Replace "MYMODULE" with the short name of the module.)

  ```
  db_query("UPDATE {system} SET weight = 100 WHERE name = 'MYMODULE');
  ```
- Instead of using `MYMODULE_form_alter()`, you can use `MYMODULE_form_user_login_block_alter(), which would not require to check the form ID.
- You should append new form submission handlers, instead of replacing the existing ones. This means you should use `$form['#submit'][] = 'user_login_submit_redirected';`.
- Functions implemented in a module should be prefixed with the short name of the module, which means "`MYMODULE_`" or "`_MYMODULE_`" (the latter is for private functions). Not using such prefix could create a compatibility issue with other module, such as the User module, as the function you are using has a name starting with "`user_`."

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and sharing your knowledge: Your additional notes are very useful for me. But I do not understand why the redirect has to be controlled over the form action. Because the code you posted (what is equal to the current drupal implementation of the user_login_block) shows that the redirect can be made with the #submit field: the drupal function [user_login_submit](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_login_submit/6) exactly does a redirect.

Comment: The code I wrote in the first code block is the code actually used from `user_login_block()`. The function is using that value for "#action" to always redirect the user to the page containing the block, and it allows to do that without using any additional function, such as a form submission handler. If you want to redirect a user that logs in using the login block, I think the only alternative you have is the one I described in my answer.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, because the user_login_submit function too does a redirect with that line: `$form_state['redirect'] = 'user/' . $user->uid;` I thout the action may not be changed, because it probably triggers the authentication, not the page after the login.

Comment: The redirect happens only from the login form, not from the login block. I tested it in my Drupal 6 test site, while viewing a node as anonymous user; once I logged in, I was not redirected to the user page. My test site doesn't have third-party modules installed; this means the behavior I described is the standard behavior for Drupal 6.

Comment: tried to follow your approach. But it did not work yet. I do not know how to make sure my code runs last of all other modules.

Comment: It worked! @kiamlaluno, you rule! Two things, kept me away from success: The `$form['#submit'][] = array('_apvs_user_login_submit');` approach did not work, the original redirect was stronger in that case, I left the `[]` away. I had to do the 3min upload.php call in the module administration. Does this upload.php has to be started after every module change? oh, dear.

Comment: It should be `$form['#submit'][] = '_apvs_user_login_submit';` as `$form['#submit']` is an array of strings. I cannot reply about upload.php, which is not a file that comes with Drupal. I can say that, if you edit the code of an installed module, you need to force Drupal to flush its cache, and you should call [menu_rebuild()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_rebuild/7) to force Drupal to call the implementations of `hook_menu()` done from the modules, otherwise it will not notice the menu definitions are changed.

Comment: Using the Devel module you would have two menu items that allow you to flush the Drupal cache, and to force Drupal to call the implementations of `hook_menu()`.

Answer (score -1):

can u try this please

```
function user_login_submit_redirected($form, &$form_state) {
  global $user;
  if ($user->uid == 0) { 
    $form_state['redirect'] = 'node/admin';
    drupal_goto('node/admin') ;
  } elseif ($user->uid) { 
    $form_state['redirect'] = 'node/add/image';
    drupal_goto('node/add/image') ;
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But it did not work. Actually I can even set an exit() or die() after the `global $user;` it has no effect, as I said, it seems not to be called at all.